# How to setup Windsor component that needs to depend on a dynamic string?

Tags: .net, asp.net, castle-windsor

I have a Castle Windsor component, that depends on a string. The string needs to be determined at runtime, based on another string, which is constant and can be set in the component configuration. How do I wire this up using Castle Windsor ?

The problem is general, but the specific scenario I need it for is a class that takes the full path to file in a constructor, but since I am running a ASP .NET app, I only know the virtual (relative) path of the file when writing the configuration file.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381734/castle-windsor-how-to-specify-a-runtime-value-as-a-parameter-e-g-value-returne

Comment: I don't agree that it is a duplicate, but it does demonstrate a technique I can use to do what I am after.

Comment: It is the same underlying problem, that's why I marked it as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No other answers here for quite a while. For reference, I created a Castle Windsor Facility to handle relative paths. It works by registering an ISubDependencyResolver, that examines the configuration for a special attribute on the dependency, and if found, invokes the custom path logic. [I blogged about the details here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130825022818/http://driis.dk/2010/02/A-Relative-Path-Facility-For-Castle-Windsor).