# Castle Windsor web.config parameters

Tags: c#, web-config, castle-windsor

I would transfer the Windor installer in the web.config of my webapplication, but I need to pass a parameter that is a static attribute of a class. There's an example:

```
// (namespace Web)

public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
{
    container.Register(
        Component.For(typeof(IRepository))
            .ImplementedBy(typeof(Repository<MyCtx>))
            .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("store", MvcApplication.GlobalStore))
            .LifestylePerWebRequest()
    );
}
```

My actual web.config:

```
<components>
  <component
      service="Core.Business.IRepository, Core"
      type="EF.Business.Repository, EF"
      lifestyle="PerWebRequest">
    <parameters>
      <store>Web.MvcAppltication.GlobalStore ???</store>
    </parameters>
  </component>
</components>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381734/castle-windsor-how-to-specify-a-runtime-value-as-a-parameter-e-g-value-return and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520849/how-to-setup-windsor-component-that-needs-to-depend-on-a-dynamic-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Castle Windsor: How to specify a runtime value as a parameter (E.g. value returned from static function call)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381734/castle-windsor-how-to-specify-a-runtime-value-as-a-parameter-e-g-value-return)

Comment: Imho this solution is not as elegant as I'd like it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I concluded that something  has to be defined in the code. Therefore I decided the way of create a facility.

My new code:

**Web.config**

```
 <component
      service="Core.Business.IRepository, Core"
      type="EF.Business.Repository`1[[EF.CreationContext, EF]], EF"
      lifestyle="PerWebRequest">
  </component>
```

**DependencyResolver.cs**

```
public class RuntimeDataSupportFacility : AbstractFacility
{
    protected override void Init()
    {
        Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new RuntimeDataDependencyResolver());
    }
}

public class RuntimeDataDependencyResolver : ISubDependencyResolver
{
    private Type[] acceptedTypes = new[] { typeof(IDictionary<String, Object>) };

    public object Resolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(dependency.TargetType, acceptedTypes[0])) // typeof(IDictionary<String, Object>
            return MvcApplication.GlobalStore;

        return null;
    }

    public bool CanResolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
    {
        if (acceptedTypes.Any(t => ReferenceEquals(t, dependency.TargetType)))
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

And on **Global.asax**.Application_Start():

```
Container =
    new WindsorContainer()
    .AddFacility<RuntimeDataSupportFacility>() // New code
    .Install(Configuration.FromAppConfig());
```